# When to use variable length array in C, but when a dynamic allocation?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free, c99

I find out about Variable Length Array in C99, but it looks like it behave almost the same as malloc + free.

The practical differences I found:

1. Too big array handling:

   ```
   unsigned size = 4000000000;
   int* ptr = malloc(size); // ptr is 0, program doesn't crash
   int array[size]; // segmentation fault, program crashes
   ```
2. Memory leaks: only possible in dynamic array allocation:

   ```
   int* ptr = malloc(size);
   ...
   if(...)
       return;
   ...
   free(ptr);
   ```
3. Life of object and possibility to return from function: dynamically allocated array lives until the memory is frees and can be returned from function which allocated the memory.
4. Resizing: resizing possible only with pointers to allocated memory.

My questions are:

- What are more differences (I'm interested in practical advice)?
- What are more problems a programmer can have with both ways of arrays with variable length?
- When to choose VLA but when dynamic array allocation?
- What is faster: VLA or malloc+free?

Comment: With `malloc()`, code knows of OOM, unlike VLA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some practical advices:

- VLAs are in practice located on the space-limited stack, while `malloc()` and its friends allocates on the heap, that is likely to allow bigger allocations. Moreveover you have more control on that process, as `malloc()` could return `NULL` if it fails. In other words you have to be careful with VLA not-to-blow your stack in runtine.
- Not all compilers support VLA, e.g. Visual Studio. Moreover [C11 marked them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29#Optional_features) as optional feature and allows not to support them when `__STDC_NO_VLA__` macro is defined.

From my experience (numerical programs like finding prime numbers with trial division, Miller-Rabin etc.) I wouldn't say that VLAs are any faster than `malloc()`. There is some overhead of `malloc()` call of course, but what seems to be more important is data access efficiency.

---

Here is some quick & dirty comparison using GNU/Linux x86-64 and GCC compiler. Note that results may vary from platform to another or even compiler's version. You might use as some basic (though **very far** of being complete) data-access `malloc()` vs VLA benchmark.

#### `prime-trial-gen.c`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool isprime(int n);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("primes.txt", "w");
    assert(fp);

    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", 2);
    for (int i = 3; i < 10000; i += 2)
        if (isprime(i))
            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

bool isprime(int n)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Compile & run:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -W prime-trial-gen.c
$ ./a.out
```

Then here is second program, that take use of generated "primes dictionary":

#### `prime-trial-test.c`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isprime(int n, int pre_prime[], int num_pre_primes);
int get_num_lines(FILE *fp);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("primes.txt", "r");
    assert(fp);

    int num_lines = get_num_lines(fp);
    rewind(fp);

#if WANT_VLA
    int pre_prime[num_lines];
#else
    int *pre_prime = malloc(num_lines * sizeof *pre_prime);
    assert(pre_prime);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
        assert(fscanf(fp, "%d", pre_prime + i));
    fclose(fp);

    /* NOTE: primes.txt holds primes <= 10 000 (10**4), thus we are safe upto 10**8 */
    int num_primes = 1; // 2
    for (int i = 3; i < 10 * 1000 * 1000; i += 2)
        if (isprime(i, pre_prime, num_lines))
            ++num_primes;
    printf("pi(10 000 000) = %d\n", num_primes);

#if !WANT_VLA
    free(pre_prime);
#endif
    return 0;
}

bool isprime(int n, int pre_prime[], int num_pre_primes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pre_primes && pre_prime[i] * pre_prime[i] <= n; ++i)
        if (n % pre_prime[i] == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int get_num_lines(FILE *fp)
{
    int ch, c = 0;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        if (ch == '\n')
            ++c;
    return c;
}
```

Compile & run (malloc version):

```
$ gcc -O2 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -W prime-trial-test.c
$ time ./a.out
pi(10 000 000) = 664579

real    0m1.930s
user    0m1.903s
sys 0m0.013s
```

Compile & run (VLA version):

```
$ gcc -DWANT_VLA=1 -O2 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -W prime-trial-test.c
ime ./a.out 
pi(10 000 000) = 664579

real    0m1.929s
user    0m1.907s
sys 0m0.007s
```

As you might [check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) `π(10**7)` is indeed `664,579`. Notice that both execution times are almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of VLAs is that you can pass variably-dimensioned arrays to functions, which can be handy when dealing with (sanely sized) matrices, for example:

```
int n = 4;
int m = 5;
int matrix[n][m];
// …code to initialize matrix…
another_func(n, m, matrix);
// No call to free()
```

where:

```
void another_func(int n, int m, int matrix[n][m])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            // …use matrix just like normal…
            sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    // …do something with sum…
}
```

This is particularly valuable since the alternatives using `malloc()` without using VLA as well mean that you either have to do subscript calculations manually in the called function, or you have to create a vector of pointers.

#### Manual subscript calculations

```
int n = 4;
int m = 5;
int *matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * n * m);
// …code to initialize matrix…
another_func2(n, m, matrix);
free(matrix);
```

and:

```
void another_func2(int n, int m, int *matrix)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            // …do manual subscripting…
            sum += matrix[i * m + j];
        }
    }
    // …do something with sum…
}
```

#### Vector of pointers

```
int n = 4;
int m = 5;
int **matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(matrix[i] * m);
// …code to initialize matrix…
another_func2(n, m, matrix);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(matrix[i]);
free(matrix);
```

and:

```
void another_func3(int n, int m, int **matrix)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            // …use matrix 'just' like normal…
            // …but there is an extra pointer indirection hidden in this notation…
            sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    // …do something with sum…
}
```

This form can be optimized to two allocations:

```
int n = 4;
int m = 5;
int **matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * n);
int *values = malloc(sizeof(*values) * n * m);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = &values[i * m];
// …code to initialize matrix…
another_func2(n, m, matrix);
free(values);
free(matrix);
```

#### Advantage VLA

There is less bookkeeping work to do when you use VLAs.  But if you need to deal with preposterously sized arrays, `malloc()` still scores.  You can use VLAs with `malloc()` et al if you're careful — see [`calloc()` for an array of array with negative index in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350717/calloc-for-an-array-of-array-with-negative-index-in-c) for an example.