# Is specifying more size than required when declaring an array a bad practice?

Tags: arrays, c, memory

In C Language, when we don't know the size of the data we're going to hold in the array. Generally, we specify more size than required. Does that not mean we're abusing the memory? Because, the array is stored in sequential manner in the memory, so the processor won't always hold those blocks for the future purpose even if they're not being used currently?

Comment: If you don't overdo it, it's ok... suppose your program needs to get a name from the user: `char name[100];` is ok `char name[1000000];` is overdoing it. If you're very **very** memory constrained use dynamic memory at the cost of time (irrelevant when dealing with user-input).

Comment: It depends on the amount of memory and how the array is defined. In C++ the std::vector allocates memory in steps so that's an example of an array-like over allocation that are working well. BTW: read about `malloc` and `realloc`

Comment: The question is very broad. Can you add some specific code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C Language, when we don't know the size of the data we're going to hold in the array. Generally, we specify more size than required.

First of all, We do not need to and do not specify more size than required in general, if we don't know the size at compile time. It might be an impression to you but that's not true.

There are two ways which are used in this case.

Using *variable length arrays* (VLAs) or *dynamic memory allocation*.

VLAs are not supported by any C implementation. They were first invented in C99 and are mandatory to implementations compliant to C99 but in implementations compliant to later C standards, *VLAs* do not need to be supported. So using VLAs makes your code non-portable (if their use is possible).

Also the capability to handling errors is when using VLAs worse. You got no way to check whether the allocation of an VLA was successful or not.

You might better use dynamic memory allocation instead if portability and/or error handling are important points.

- [malloced array VS. variable-length-array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16672322/12139179)
- [Is it a good idea to use C99 VLA compared to malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082126)
- [Is it safe to use variable-length arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326547)
- [When to use variable length array in C, but when a dynamic allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337168)

Beside that you can resize and free the no longer needed memory if you like to with dynamic memory, which isn't possible with VLAs.

---

> Is specifying more size than required when declaring an array a bad practice?

Speaking about static allocated arrays with size fixed at compile-time, specifying more size than required is **not** a bad practice in general. Of course, you will probably waste some memory but it is always a good decision to stay safe than to have real serious trouble when you need more memory or try to access memory beyond the bounds by accident which invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/12139179).

However, if the amount of the waste size is enormous and the range between the possible sizes is drastically, then you should really use dynamic memory allocation instead. For example a case where you do not know if you need 10 or 100000 elements up-front and you allocate 100000 elements just to be safe. That would be kind of bad practice.

It is also better to use dynamic memory in this case because the stack isn't as large as the heap memory.

Short summary: If you really don't want to waste any memory and want to be safe, use dynamic memory allocation instead of anything else.

Comment: `instead if portability is an important point.` No, portability is not (that big of) an issue. Error handling is an issue - do not use variable length arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice when you specify a very huge size like `1000000000000`, etc. in those places where most of the elements are being unused.

There's no problem to specify the array size a few larger than the number of required elements.

Although, the variable array length is allowed in C99. In some situations, you may ask the user to define the array size by their own.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. If the memory resource you have for a particular program is not large enough that you fear to allocate more space than what you need, then you should use *Dynamic Memory Allocation*.
To apply this mechanism you need to learn as basic: `calloc`, `malloc`, `realloc` from *https://www.cplusplus.com/* or other docs you like